# Extract one column value based on the first instance value in another column

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, transform, data-manipulation

I have a data table given below along with dput for two scenarios.

DT1:

```
  date      item id
 1: 2016-09-05  view  1
 2: 2016-09-05  view  1
 3: 2016-09-05  view  1
 4: 2016-09-06    pv  1
 5: 2016-09-06    pv  1
 6: 2016-09-06    pv  1
 7: 2016-09-06 check  1
 8: 2016-09-06 check  1
 9: 2016-09-06 check  1
10: 2016-09-06 check  1
```

dput1:

```
DT = setDT(structure(list(date = structure(c(17049, 17049, 17049, 17050, 
17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050), class = "Date"), item = c("view", 
"view", "view", "pv", "pv", "pv", "check", "check", "check", 
"check"), id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("date", 
"item", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame")))
```

DT2:

```
date     item id
 1: 2016-09-05  view  1
 2: 2016-09-05  view  1
 3: 2016-09-05  view  1
 4: 2016-09-08    pv  1
 5: 2016-09-06   pv1  1
 6: 2016-09-06   pv2  1
 7: 2016-09-06 check  1
 8: 2016-09-06 check  1
 9: 2016-09-06 check  1
10: 2016-09-06 check  1
```

dput2:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(17049, 17049, 17049, 17050, 
17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050), class = "Date"), item = c("view", 
"view", "view", "pv", "pv1", "pv2", "check", "check", "check", 
"check"), id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("date", 
"item", "id"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000210788>)
```

I am trying to find the date for the first occurrence of pv in the 'item' column and extract the corresponding date for that entry then extract the date for the first occurrence of check in the 'item' by id, take the difference in days and store in a new variable.

Also what if there are multiple conditions that we need to check for 'pv'. For example if 'pv' is not in the list then 'pv1' can be checked or 'pv2'. The idea is to get the first occurrence. So if there is pv, pv1 and pv2 but pv2 appears first then the date corresponding to pv2 should be taken. Similarly, it can be that only 'pv2' or 'pv1' or 'pv' is present in the item column. How can we perform a check to take the first occurrence out of the three possibilities and extract the date. Any idea?

Looking for thoughts and suggestion on getting it done using minimum code possible with data table or `%>%`.

Answer (score 4):

If 'dt' is the 'data.table' object, after grouping by 'id', we get the index of the first occurrence of 'pv' (`which.max(item=="pv")`) and 'check', subset the 'date' based on that index, subtract it and assign (`:=`) it to new variable 'Diff'.

```
dt[, Diff := date[which.max(item == "pv")]- date[which.max(item =="check")], by = id]
```

---

Or instead of `which.max`, use `match` to get the index

```
dt[, Diff := date[match("pv", item)] - date[match("check", item)], by = id]
```

NOTE 1: Assumption is that all the 'id's have at least one 'pv' and 'check'.

NOTE 2: If we need the difference in specific units, use `difftime` and specify the `units`

Comment: ``ndays <- as.numeric(diff(as.Date(c(dt[item=="pv"][1]$date,
    dt[item=="check"][1]$date)
)))`` just to demonstrate how to use ``difftime``

Comment: @akrun - can we also include a check in above code or separately to check if the date for when item is 'check' is greater than the date when item is "pv"?

Comment: @nathanesau The `difftime` argument might be `difftime(date[which.max(item == "pv")], date[which.max(item == "check")], unit = "day")`

Comment: @syebill Yes, you can do that, perhaps, `dt[, c("Diff", "DateCheck") := {v1 <- date[match("pv", item)] - date[match("check", item)]; v2 <- v1 < 0; list(v1, v2) }, by = id]`

Comment: First date sounds like min, not max...?

Comment: I will give it a try and will come back with feedback but looks like it will work. Thanks.

Comment: @Frank  I guess the OP wanted the corresponding date for the first occurence of 'pv' or 'check'.  Do you think I am wrong?

Comment: Ah ok, you are using which.max on a logical, which is what confused me, and apparently relying on sorting by date as well as the presence of some TRUE values in that logical (as mentioned in your note 1). Now it makes sense to me, though something like `DT[, {mins = tapply(date, item, min); mins["pv"] - mins["check"]}, by=id]` would be easier for me to follow. As a side note, it's not at all clear to me what behavior will ensue when the assumptions are violated.

Comment: @Frank I haven't tested a case where one of the values are not there or both not present in a particular id.  So, i thought to make an assumption in case it breaks.

Comment: @akrun - what if there are multiple conditions that we need to check for 'pv'. For example if 'pv' is not in the list then 'pv1' can be checked or 'pv2'. The idea is to get the first occurrence. So if there is pv, pv1 and pv2 but pv2 appears first then the date corresponding to pv2 should be taken. Any idea?

Comment: @syebill Could you post that as a new question as it is not clear from the comments